# Will object with reference kept be disposed?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

May I know if the "objectToBeDisposed" will be disposed if its reference are kept by the "useDisposableObject"?

```
using(IDisposable objectToBeDisposed = new ObjectImplementedIDisposable  ()){
ChildObject useDisposableObject = new ChildObject(objectToBeDisposed);
.... doing stuff with useDisposableObject;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disposal, finalization and memory deallocation are 3 totally different things in the .NET world.

Disposal is only an "application logic" thing, it is implemented through the disposable pattern.
If you implement the interface IDisposable, your object can be used with the using keyword.

The using keyword will translate in a simple way:

```
using (IDisposable xxx = new MyObject())
{
    ....
}
```

means

```
{
    IDisposable xxx = new MyObject();
    try
    {
        ....
    }
    finally
    {
        if (xxx != null)
            xxx.Dispose();
    }
}
```

There is no other magic in this. That's all.

Object finalization is instead called by garbage collector when the objects should be freed.
The time when it happens and the order between destructors is unpredictable.

```
class myclass { ~myclass() { this code will be called by garbage collector, i cannot call it } }
```

The syntax is very similar to C++ destructors but the meaning is a lot different.

And then memory deallocation.
Memory deallocation is not connected to object disposal!
You can keep forever a reference to a disposed object. Disposal is just something related to application logic.

Destructors can also be cancelled or called more than once by garbage collector (see GC.ReRegisterForFinalize and GC.SuppressFinalize).
The presence of a destructor in a class slow down a lot the garbage collector, and inside destructor, you can do almost nothing except releasing unmanaged resources.

Disposal instead as I said is an application thing, is just a method, and is not related to garbage collector.

Comment: +1; The try/finally code is close, and captures the spirit of what is happening, but it isn't quite correct.  It also creates a logical block around the whole bit of code, and checks for `xxx != null` before calling `Dispose()`.  These both are useful aspects of the `using` block.  See this code project article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tinguusingstatement.aspx

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham I guess this more complete specification is clear too :) thanks.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham Thank you very much for your time to explain the concept to us.

Comment: Although C# destructors and C++ destructors share the name and syntax, they otherwise have nothing in common.  Note that the purpose of a destructor in C# isn't to eliminate the object in question, but rather to *delay* the elimination of an abandoned object and allow it to notify other entities that it no longer needs their services.

Comment: @supercat Well, it is used mostly to dealloc unmanaged resources, for example, if you have a class for an HBITMAP, you have to implement both IDisposable and ensure that in destructor you relese the unmanaged resource if it was not released by Dispose. They are not C++ destructor, as I said in my post, but they have their syntax. See the System.ComponentModel.Component class, it implements IDIsposable and have a destructor, it calls the protected virtual method Dispose(bool disposing), disposing is true if Dispose was called in Dispose(), is false if called by destructor.

Comment: @Salvatore Previti: When you create an HBITMAP, you are asking the GDI to maintain an object associated with the handle.  It will maintain that object "forever" until it is told it is no longer needed.  To ensure that the object doesn't get held forever, some entity must take on the responsibility for ensuring the GDI will get notified when the handle isn't needed anymore.  Objects with such responsibilities generally use IDisposable.Dispose to carry them out.  Objects can also ask to have the system call Finalize() if it determines that they've been abandoned.

Comment: @Salvatore Previti: The essential observation is that the "resource" isn't in the object itself.  It might or might not be scarce, it might or might not exist entirely within managed code (as with event subscriptions), it might or might not be something that can accept asynchronous cleanup notification, and it might or might not even be on the same computer as the object that holds the responsibility of cleaning it up.  Just about the only thing certain is that a finalizer/destructor that doesn't access anything outside the object is, outside scenarios involving object resurrection, useless.

Comment: @Salvatore, supercat: Now that supercat brings it up - I haven't used C++/CLI, but isn't a "destructor" something separate and special in that language?  If so, I think the term "finalizer" would be most correct here.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham Yes, I agree, finalizer is the right name for that. Corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, in your example it will be disposed, because the using block explicitly calls the `Dispose()` method when leaving that block.

As an aside the referencing object is within the using block scope and will go out of scope at the end of the using block, which will avoid the potential issue of accessing a disposed object if the referencing object tried to use it once it was disposed.

**Update thanks to @dlev**

Comment: Right answer, though wrong reasoning: `objectToBeDisposed` would be disposed no matter what objects had references to it, that's just what a `using` block does. Whether or not it is *GCed* is a different story, but totally unrelated to whether or not it is disposed.

Comment: @John Weldon Thanks you for your fast response!

Answer (score 3):

"Disposing" an object has nothing to do with which references are kept around.  `IDisposable` itself is just an interface, nothing more.

When a class implements that interface, a user of the class can call a `public void Dispose()` method on the object.  When the user of the class places an instance of the class in a `using` block, the `Dispose()` method will automatically get called.  When an `Enumerator` class implements `IDisposable` and is used in a `foreach` loop, it will also have `Dispose()` called on it.

This has absolutely nothing to do with which references are kept around, or the automatic garbage collection system.

However, `IDisposable` also has a design "contract" that goes with it.  This contract is a pattern that classes that implement `IDisposable` must follow to have correct program behavior.

The contract is that once you've called `Dispose()`, you should never call any property or method on the object again, otherwise you should expect an `ObjectDisposedException` to be thrown.  The only thing that is allowed to be called on that object after that point is `Dispose()` again, or the object finalizer (via garbage collection).

Because of this, people will sometimes set an reference to an `IDisposable` class to `null` after they have disposed it, so they don't accidentally call methods on the already-disposed object.  If you placed the reference in a `using` block, you don't have to worry about this;  The compiler won't even let you touch the reference again.  If you try, you will get an error and your program will fail to compile.

This contract is *not* built into the language or CLR itself - it must manually be adhered to by the implementer of a class.

Comment: Objects which implement IDIsposable may, in some cases, usefully specify that certain properties or methods will remain available.  A communications object, for example, may have properties which report how much data has been exchanged during the lifetime of the connection.  In some cases, such statistics might not be meaningful until after the collection has been closed.  While it might seem "cleaner" to for a client to use Close, then read the properties, and then call Dispose, I see little to be gained by enforcing such a pattern.

Comment: @supercat: What you say sort of makes sense, but there are some aspects that trouble me.  They're technically free to do that (like I said, the contract is enforced by the implementer), but that's a re-definition of the implicit contract.  At the very least that would have to be documented in SDK docs, and probably in triple-slash comments.  I'd personally think it would surprise users, too, so I wouldn't recommend you do it if you could think of a better design.  Do you have an example of classes in the framework that do this? Sometimes I don't know that classes I use are `IDisposable` :)

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: As I see it, the IDisposable contract has three parts: (1) an entity creating an IDisposable has the responsibility of ensuring that Dispose gets called, either by doing the Dispose itself, or handing the object to some other entity that will accept the responsibility; (2) an entity creating an IDisposable has the responsibility of not doing anything with the object after Dispose, *other than what the particular type of object promises to allow*; (3) the IDisposable object must take care of all required cleanup when Dispose is called, without requiring anything else.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: The IDisposable contract does not specify what should happen if a party does not abide by it.  An IDisposable object is free to do almost whatever it wants, at least with regard to the IDisposable contract, if members other than Dispose are accessed after Dispose has been called.  The situation is somewhat like Undefined Behavior in C.  The C standard says that signed integer overflow is Undefined Behavior, but a fully-compliant compiler may specify that such overflows will wrap in a certain way.  In the case of post-dispose member access, it is better...

Comment: @supercat: That's a fair way to think about it, and will keep everyone from running into trouble.  But I'd avoid creating classes that rely on that looser definition of #2.  `IDisposable` objects are often placed in a `using` block, which would eliminate the usefulness of that flexibility.  And users would have to read separate documentation for your class, or you'd have to have strategic placement in your Intellisense comments (e.g. mentioning special-case properties in the constructor - kind of gross) for those special case properties to be discoverable.

Comment: @supercat: Yes, nothing enforces that contract but good will of users and good will of implementers.  But the implicit contract exists, whether the specifications cover it or not.  And no, I hardly ever bother writing IsDisposed code myself, but I never rely on this omission.  But as I just commented, I think your looser definition can be okay, as long as that loosening of the contract is easily discoverable without referring to external docs.

Comment: ...to throw ObjectDisposedException than act in any other manner which doesn't fulfill the member's contract.  On the other hand, if there is a possible action which would fulfill the member's contract, such action may be preferable to throwing an exception.  BTW, there's at least one .net class which can be very useful after disposal: Font.  One can set the Font property of a control to a font which has been Disposed and the system will be perfectly happy.  If the Font isn't needed for any other purpose, disposing it early is cleaner than having it keep its useless GDI handle.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: One should generally avoid reliance upon members being available after disposal *except when a class explicitly documents that they will be* (arguably, the behavior of Font in that regard is well-enough established to qualify; it's too bad Microsoft didn't use a FontInfo class for the Control.Font property, since that would have been a cleaner design).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be. I might be wrong, but I don't think @John Weldon's explanation is not accurate though. You can only call using on an `IDisposable` implementing class, and when the using exits, it will call `Dispose()` on the object.

The part where I don't agree is the 'because the referencing object is within the using block scope and will go out of scope at the end of the using block' part. The objects declared in scope will not always be disposed of when the using exits. If you take this example

```
JustAClass myInstance = new JustAClass();
using ( MyDisposableClass theUsingInstance = new MyDisposableClass() )
{
    AnotherClass innerInstance = new AnotherClass();
    myInstance.ItsOtherClass = innerInstance;
    myInstance.ItsWhatever = theUsingInstance;
}
```

At the end of this code, `myInstance.ItsOtherClass` is not `null`. `innerInstance` has been created in the using section and won't be garbage collected since there is still a referenced. However, the object refered by `myInstance.ItsWhatever` has been disposed of, since it's the `using` target.

Comment: I didn't say that the referencing class would be disposed... simply that it would go out of scope.